# Implementing IRC RFC: How to respond to MODE?

Tags: irc

I'm trying to code my own IRC server. I'm referencing the IRC RFC but it's a little confusing to me. If I were to go strictly off the RFC, I don't think any of the popular clients would work with my server, like mIRC. For example, the RFC says that the server should respond to a successful MODE command one of the following numeric responses:`RPL_BANLIST`, `RPL_CHANNELMODEIS`, `RPL_ENDOFBANLIST`, `RPL_UMODEIS`. This would lead me to believe that on a successful user mode change, I'd respond with RPL_UMODEIS, although the RFC doesn't seem to explicitly state so.

But, when I check the source code to another open source IRC server, I see that it responds with a non-numeric command of 'MODE'. It just echos back the MODE command it looks like.

How are you supposed to respond to the MODE command? Is there a better formatted RFC that has a simple command and response chart, or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RFC 1459 is famously sparse.  It does not tell you everything you need to know to write a server.

In this case, what's missing is the distinction between a `MODE` command that queries an existing mode, and a `MODE` command that sets a new mode.  In the case of a mode query, a client will receive a numeric reply that indicates the existing mode; in the case of altering a mode, a client will not receive a direct numeric reply unless there was an error.  However, if the mode *was* successfully altered, then a client will recieve a `MODE` from the server informing it of the change.

So for example, if the client's nick is `foo` and it sends:

```
MODE foo
```

then this is querying its current usermode - it will expect a `RPL_UMODEIS` reply like:

```
:irc.example.org 221 foo :+i
```

If the client then sends:

```
MODE foo :+w
```

then this is altering its usermode - it will either get a numeric error like `ERR_USERSDONTMATCH` or an acknowledgement of the mode change:

```
:foo!foo@bar.com MODE foo :+w
```

Note that this acknowledgement is technically not a direct reply to the `MODE` - it's the server informing the client of a relevant change in its state, which happens to have been triggered by a client command.

A similar situation exists with channel modes.  If a client queries the current channel modes with:

```
MODE #channel
```

then it will expect a `RPL_CHANNELMODEIS` response containing the current "simple" channel modes, and perhaps a `RPL_CREATIONTIME`response giving the channel creation time.  If it queries for the current ban list with:

```
MODE #channel b
```

then should get zero or more `RPL_BANLIST` responses, followed by a `RPL_ENDOFBANLIST`.

If instead a client tries to change a channel mode:

```
MODE #channel :+k zounds
```

then the direct reply will either be an error reply or nothing; and if the channel mode was actually changed, it will see the `MODE` command echoed back.  In the latter case the successful `MODE` command will also be sent to the other members of the channel - this helps to illustrate that it's not really a direct reply to the initial `MODE` command, but an indirect response to it.

Comment: Where do I get the necessary information for building a proper IRC server? How did you learn this?

Comment: IRC is more defined through tribal knowledge and custom, the best place to get the necessary information is to investigate what fairly standard servers (eg. ircd-hybrid, ircd-ratbox, ircu, unreal) do in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be the user mode string. Typically the responses are:

- for +/- b modes: `RPL_BANLIST` and/or the ban list then `RPL_ENDOFBANLIST`
- for channel modes: `RPL_CHANNELMODEIS`
- for use rmodes: `RPL_UMODEIS`

Sometimes MODE commands are issued not to change a mode but to list it (like +b without any arguments). So in response, you give whatever the appropriate numeric code is and just spit back the mode(s). There's a bit more info about what to expect back from the server in the [RFC 2812 update to RFC 1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812) which focuses more on the client.